# When is it relevant to consider a trace as a RF transmission line

Tags: rf, transmission-line, impedance-matching

I'm building a simple Greinacher based RF Power meter for the PMR band i.e 446MHz.
I intend it to work as a confirmation device and not something really acurate.

The circuit is quite simple:
[image: Greinacher schematic]

The led is for visual control if the system works well.

I have obtained the Following routing (without the LED):
[image: Routing picture]

From left to right: I have the input SMA, with a transmission line adapted to 50Ohms.
Which goes into the C1 capacitor, then in the diodes, and then in the C3 capacitor.

**Is it relevant to consider the trace between C1 and D1 and between D1 and C3 as transmission lines?**
They are short L < 4mm, for a wavelength of around 70cm.
For the moment I have used the embedded calculator in kicad to find the dimensions of the transmission line used :
[image]

Comment: I suppose, you will be connecting an antenna? That's why you are willing to keep everything matched to 50Ohms ?
It may be a subject for another question but you might want to make something to smoothly convert the wide line to the width of the first capacitor.

Comment: You are right, I intend to use it to measure without precision the power emitted by a device. And I will be connecting this small board to a dipole antenna.
That's a great suggestion I didn't thought of that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bit of research and to be considered as a transmission line you would need at least Lambda/10. This is at this point that we consider that along the line you don't have the same voltage.
This is also true for power lines!

This at your frequency give a length of at least 6.7cm which you are well below.